# SQLiteException when executing query

Tags: java, android

I want to execute a ManagedQuery but am getting a error in my log:

**Query**

```
 Cursor cursor = managedQuery(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI,projection,Notes.NOTE_TITLE+"="+S+" AND "+ Notes.NOTE_DATE+"="+S1, null, null);
```

**Error Log**

```
02-21 16:00:52.395: E/AndroidRuntime(22534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.schuemie.GroceryList/net.schuemie.GroceryList.shoppinglist}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "new": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT item_name FROM notes WHERE (title=shop new AND date=12/2/12) ORDER BY title
```

Comment: It's not a compilation error, it's a runtime error, hence `RuntimeException` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update***

```
String where = "title='"+nameOfTitle+"' And date="+date+" "; 


Cursor cursor = managedQuery(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI,null,where,null,null);
```

Comment: using this query i printed in log cat to see hw many rows its returning but it is showing as zero.............bt when i keep the where clause part as null it will print in the log that there are four rows..........y do i have this error??

Comment: can u post that both query which u r printing in your logcat

Comment: Cursor cursor = managedQuery(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI,null,Notes.NOTE_TITLE+"='"+S+"' AND "+ Notes.NOTE_DATE+"="+S1, null, null);when i use this it returns zero rows

Comment: Cursor cursor = managedQuery(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI,null,null, null, null);when i use this it returns four rows which are present in the database

Comment: is there anyone who could give a solution for this??

Comment: but still am having the same problem when i do this

Comment: just remove projection at that place put null & check

Comment: i checked that earlier but no use

Comment: i have checked it & it is giving correct row you just check again my answer now i have placed only one answer there.

Answer (score 1):

remove "new" from query and add quotes to string values

```
SELECT item_name FROM notes WHERE (title='shop' AND date=12/2/12) ORDER BY title
```

Comment: SELECT item_name FROM notes WHERE (title=shop new AND date=12/2/12) ORDER BY title - this is your query from error log. look carefully, new can be in title field value, so your query must look loke this SELECT item_name FROM notes WHERE (title='shop new' AND date=12/2/12) ORDER BY title

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do this

```
title="shop"
```

or

```
title='shop'
```

Comment: S is currently my title and checking it with my column name in my database